# QGraphicsItem under cursor at leaving object while over another item

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView and some QGraphicsItems subclassed.
I want to track which item is under the cursor topmost visible.
It works fine using hoverEnterEvent in most situations, but if I have two Objects where one is on top of another it does work on entering both but not on leaving the inner object (and re-entering the outer, since it never left the outer in the first place).

```
           +-------------------------------------+
  outside  |                                     |
           |  outer                              |
           |                                     |
           |                                     |
           |           +-------------+           |     +-------------+ 
           |           |             |           |     |             | 
           |           |             |           |     |   another   |
           |           |    inner    |           |     |             |
           |           |             |           |     |             |
           |           |             |           |     +-------------+ 
           |           +-------------+           |
           |                                     |
           |                                     |
           |                                     |
           |                                     |
           +-------------------------------------+

outside -> outer : works, outer is selected
outside -> outer -> outside -> another : works, first outside is selected, than nothing, than another
outer -> inner : works, inner is seletected
outside -> outer -> inner -> outer: does not work, first outside is selected, than inner, but than nothing (should be outer again)
```

What can I do, besides looping trough all graphicitems triggered via a slight delayed singleshot on hoverLeaveEvent?

Edit:
I found a temporary solution:
I added a global QList < MyQGraphicsItem *> where on MyQGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent I add "this", and on MyGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent I remove the last item in the List. So the myGlobalQList.last() always contains the topmost item visible under the cursor.
I assume this is not the best solution since QList is not threadsafe, therefor I am still interested in other solutions.

Comment: Your `QList<QGraphicsItem*>` solution isn't that bad after all - your `QGraphicsScene` isn't thread-safe itself, so you don't have to worry about `QList`. Semantically you'd use a `QStack` ([LIFO](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_In_%E2%80%93_First_Out)), *but generally* I recommend to try using `QGraphicsScene::itemAt(QPointF pos)` *instead*. That's fast enough and you don't need to worry about keeping your `QList` up to date.

Comment: **For us to answer your question more specifically, you really should explain what you want to achieve when you know the topmost item.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `QGraphicsItem`s live in a `QGraphicsScene` which can be displayed by **one or more** `QGraphicsView`s.

I know that the model-view mapping usually is 1:1.

Still I suggest to implement mouse handling like this in your view, not in the scene:

Install an `eventFilter` on your `graphicsView->viewport()`.

Override the `eventFilter()` function in your filter class.

Watch for `QEvent::MousePress`, `MouseMove`, `MouseRelease`, maybe `Enter` and `Leave`, depending on what you need.

Probably you need to `setMouseTracking(true)` on the viewport.

Then, in the event filter function, use `QGraphicsView::mapToScene()` and `QGraphicsScene::itemAt()` to find the topmost item, or `::items()` to find all items under the cursor.

I recently used this to decorate the topmost item with a border by painting over the view (`QGraphicsView::drawForeground()`).

Comment: Martin Hennings: but how?

Comment: @user2567875 I expanded my answer. For me to answer your question more specifically, you really should add what you want to achieve when you know the topmost item.

Comment: Martin Hennings: I could not find anything about QGraphicsModel. Can you add a link to the relevant part of the documentation? I found a  temporary solution, and added it to the question above. I simple need to know which is the topmost item, but doing the maptoscene/mapfromview stuff seems rather expensive. Iff I can get access on the ItemTree, it should be relativly cheap, but I dont have any clue on how to do that. I will see if the temporary solution is "good enough" and iff not (as I assume) dig into it deeper later. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I meant [`QGraphicsScene`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html). The mapping is not really expensive, it's a simple matrix operation. Whatever you do with querying the mouse cursor and whatever you show the user - you need 20+ frames per second to make it fluid. That's a lot of CPU cycles per frame, so don't worry about `QGraphicsView` performance.